How to add traces/spans to async function?
I'm having trouble adding tracing to a particular function in my rust project. Here are the relevant files
// chain/ethereum/src/ingestor.rs

    #[tracing::instrument(skip(self), name = "PollingBlockIngestor::do_poll")]
    async fn do_poll(&self) -> Result<(), IngestorError> {

        // Get chain head ptr from store
        let head_block_ptr_opt = self.chain_store.cheap_clone().chain_head_ptr().await?;

        // To check if there is a new block or not, fetch only the block header since that's cheaper
        // than the full block. This is worthwhile because most of the time there won't be a new
        // block, as we expect the poll interval to be much shorter than the block time.
        info_span!("latest_block");
        let latest_block = self.latest_block().await?;

        if let Some(head_block) = head_block_ptr_opt.as_ref() {
            // If latest block matches head block in store, nothing needs to be done
            if &latest_block == head_block {
                return Ok(());
            }

            if latest_block.number < head_block.number {
                // An ingestor might wait or move forward, but it never
                // wavers and goes back. More seriously, this keeps us from
                // later trying to ingest a block with the same number again
                warn!(self.logger,
                    "Provider went backwards - ignoring this latest block";
                    "current_block_head" => head_block.number,
                    "latest_block_head" => latest_block.number);
                return Ok(());
            }
        }

        // Compare latest block with head ptr, alert user if far behind
        match head_block_ptr_opt {
            None => {
                info!(
                    self.logger,
                    "Downloading latest blocks from Ethereum, this may take a few minutes..."
                );
            }
            Some(head_block_ptr) => {
                let latest_number = latest_block.number;
                let head_number = head_block_ptr.number;
                let distance = latest_number - head_number;
                let blocks_needed = (distance).min(self.ancestor_count);
                let code = if distance >= 15 {
                    LogCode::BlockIngestionLagging
                } else {
                    LogCode::BlockIngestionStatus
                };
                if distance > 0 {
                    info!(
                        self.logger,
                        "Syncing {} blocks from Ethereum",
                        blocks_needed;
                        "current_block_head" => head_number,
                        "latest_block_head" => latest_number,
                        "blocks_behind" => distance,
                        "blocks_needed" => blocks_needed,
                        "code" => code,
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        let mut missing_block_hash = self.ingest_block(&latest_block.hash).await?;

        
        while let Some(hash) = missing_block_hash {
            missing_block_hash = self.ingest_block(&hash).await?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    async fn latest_block(&self) -> Result<BlockPtr, IngestorError> {
        info_span!("latest_block_header");
        self.eth_adapter
            .latest_block_header(&self.logger)
            .compat()
            .await
            .map(|block| block.into())
    }

and
// chain/ethereum/src/ethereum_adapter.rs

impl EthereumAdapterTrait for EthereumAdapter {

    #[tracing::instrument(skip_all, name = "testest")]
    fn latest_block_header(
        &self,
        logger: &Logger,
    ) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = web3::types::Block<H256>, Error = IngestorError> + Send> {
        let s = info_span!("latest_block_header in eth adapter");
        let web3 = self.web3.clone();
        Box::new(
            retry("eth_getBlockByNumber(latest) no txs RPC call", logger)
                .no_limit()
                .timeout_secs(ENV_VARS.json_rpc_timeout.as_secs())
                .run(move || {
                    let web3 = web3.cheap_clone();
                    async move {
                        let block_opt = web3
                            .eth()
                            .block(Web3BlockNumber::Latest.into())
                            .await
                            .map_err(|e| {
                                anyhow!("could not get latest block from Ethereum: {}", e)
                            })?;

                        block_opt
                            .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("no latest block returned from Ethereum").into())
                    }
                })
                .map_err(move |e| {
                    e.into_inner().unwrap_or_else(move || {
                        anyhow!("Ethereum node took too long to return latest block").into()
                    })
                })
                .boxed()
                .compat(),
        )
    }
// lots of other functions
}

When I run this and send the traces to Jaeger, I don't see either of the spans on latest_block_header. I see PollingBlockIngestor::do_poll and latest_block and latest_block_header but don't see testest nor latest_block_header in eth adapter.

How do I correctly create spans for the latest_block_header function?
EDIT: I also tried modifying the async move like so where I call instrument on the future but that also doesn't work.
                    let web3 = web3.cheap_clone();
                    let s = info_span!("latest_block_header in eth adapter");
                    async move {
                        let block_opt = web3
                            .eth()
                            .block(Web3BlockNumber::Latest.into())
                            .instrument(s)
                            .await
                            .map_err(|e| {
                                anyhow!("could not get latest block from Ethereum: {}", e)
                            })?;

                        block_opt
                            .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("no latest block returned from Ethereum").into())
                    }


Turns out I had my filters set up incorrectly. They were
        let filter_layer = EnvFilter::try_new(
            "graph_chain_ethereum::ingestor,reqwest_tracing::reqwest_otel_span_builder",
        )

I needed to add graph_chain_ethereum::ethereum_adapter to the list and then everything worked flawlessly.

Just creating the span doesn't "enter" it. I don't know for sure if an un-entered span would mean it is missing in Jaeger (via opentelemetry), but regardless...
To "enter" a span, you need to either:

use .enter() or .entered() which will return an RAII guard type that will exit the span once dropped. The only difference between the two is simply whether the span is consumed or just referenced.
use .in_scope(|| { ... }) to wrap the enclosed code in that span.
use .instrument(span) extension method on a Future / async { ... } block. That will automatically enter and exit as the task is polled.

You likely want the last option since it is specifically for tracing async tasks.
Putting it on the inner async block would mean that it only covers that portion of your code and if re-ran (assuming that's what retry(...) might do) there would be multiple "latest_block_header in eth adapter" spans within your "latest_block_header" span.
use tracing::Instrument;

let s = info_span!("latest_block_header in eth adapter");
async move {
    ...
}.instrument(s)

If you instead wanted it to cover the whole retry(...) operation, you could tack it on the end:
let s = info_span!("latest_block_header in eth adapter");

Box::new(
    retry("eth_getBlockByNumber(latest) no txs RPC call", logger)
        .no_limit()
        .timeout_secs(...)
        .run(...)
        .map_err(...)
        .boxed()
        .compat()
        .instrument(s),
)


Hmm, I would have guessed that the annotation should work. Interesting that the span usage in the other methods automatically enters it. Adding the instrument to the end of the retry doesn't work because the final type isn't a Future which is required by Box. I also tried using instrument in the edit I posted to the OP. That also didn't work.

I'm wondering if this issue is arising because the function returns a Box<Future>>?

Oh, is the Future like from futures v0.1 or something? That does complicate things, but it shouldn't really affect the inner stuff - like async { }.instrument() should still work so long as it ends up running at all.

Here's the latest version of the function: https://gist.github.com/paymog/0ceb78953c37a2aea0f2cee0f2df0c08
I added two instrument calls with an inner span and outer span. Neither seem to be getting sent to jaeger. I also added an info log at the beginning of the function and I can definitely see that log being emitted.

Its been a while since I used Jaeger, do nested spans show up in the "Operations" list or is is just root spans? Can you verify by viewing the specific span tree? If its not that, do you have any configuration that may be filtering out spans? It definitely sounds like something other than what I answered is going on, can you try to provide a [mre] that I could run that shows this behavior?

Nested spans do show up in Jaeger: https://imgur.com/a/vkm0Cq2. Individual spans can also be searched (which is shown in the image in the OP). I can try to do a minimal reproducible example.

well this is interesting, I added this function: https://gist.github.com/paymog/eb716a1ac6490a085799ff4fd94e90dd and call it like this: https://gist.github.com/paymog/e801d67f92a9695ff44f00b011d3a2b8. The spans from the new function don't show up either. The class these functions live on implements a trait that looks like this: https://gist.github.com/paymog/d997e8fddc932ce4ccad82b75c08aa0f. Could it be the trait causing issues?

I don't imagine the trait is causing the issue. Are you 100% sure the code you are running includes your changes? Is it calling the implementation you think it should? And are you looking at new spans in Jaeger? Starting to feel like we're barking up the wrong tree...

Yeah quite sure that this code I'm copy-pasting is what's running because i see the logs from the 4th comment in this chain. I'm also running this in an IDE and can see it compile with every change.
